# Paper JS fill color closed paths

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm making a drawing tool using Paper JS. Now I want to fill a closed path from two items, say for example two rectangles that intersects.

Looking at the reference there seems to be a function to get the intersections but does not accomplish what I need as it makes another shape out of the intersection.

`intersect(item)` or `subtract(item)`

[image]

Also in this scenario where it detects if the object is split.

[image]

If any of you guys have come across this issue please give some advice.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It looks like PaperJS doesn't have a way to do this automatically. You might have to do some boolean maths yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice [demo of boolean operations](http://paperjs.org/examples/boolean-operations/) in the paper.js examples.

Use [`Path.unite()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#unite-path), [`Path.intersect()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#intersect-path) (and not `Path.intersects()`), [`Path.subtract()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#subtract-path), [`Path.exclude()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#exclude-path) to compute boolean operations.

You can also use [`Path.getIntersections()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections-path) or maybe the more appropriate [`Path.getCrossings()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getcrossings-path) to handle intersections with opened path.

Comment: whoa cool. will definitely look at the demo, was stuck in the reference page. thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I added details about intersections with opened path

Comment: will try the getCrossings() as I have already tried the getIntersections(). Guess can start from here. Thanks for helping out!